# Which algorithm to use when finding shortest path in multiple overlapping datasets?

Tags: python, algorithm, path, shortest

I've been tasked with writing an algorithm in Python that is able to establish the shortest journey on a metro train system. The train network has multiple train "lines", which consist of different stations. Some stations are featured on multiple different lines. It essentially works exactly the same as the London tube network. I've been given the stations and the lines, as well as the time between each station, which will act as the cost in the algorithm. Could someone give me a brief idea of how I should approach this? Thanks.

I'm aware Dijkstra's would be the best algorithm to use for this, I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around how to actually approach it.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. What is the problem with constructing a single graph with all train stations of all lines (and appropriate connections between them) and then running Dijkstra or A* on it?

Comment: My issue is I cant figure out how to specify the source node and destination node using an input, currently the algo is only able to print off the times between each node and a single source node.

Comment: Did you try storing the nodes in a dictionary with the station names as key? Its not very productive to ask for help without showing us your code, since you do have something to start with.